# How do I handle pop up in katalon studio for a website that's built on REACT?

Tags: katalon-studio

While recording a specific step in katalon studio, and replaying it I get error. See attachment. I am trying to click on # linked button that opens a pop up and then I click on x icon to close the popup.

Second is a dropdown button, on click, it opens a dropdown, clicking outside of it closes the dropdown.

I am new to katalon and don't understand that while recording manually the objects do get captured but when I play them I get error ( shared below)

This is the URL: juggernaut.in

[In this image I have highlighted where I want click actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTjCM.jpg)

[this is the error on click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J5QF.png)

Comment: Pls share attachment

Comment: Attachments added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because , the js is loading and katalon is not able to find objects, you could just use WebUI.delay() after or before action function and manually enter delay time by hit and trial and then check

Comment: No no NO! Do NOT use `WebUI.delay()`! It is code smell!

Comment: https://forum.katalon.com/t/ways-to-avoid-having-to-sleep-delay-your-code/83302